# inner join 3 tables, condition where not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have problem with below query. Condition where c.startime is not working and it returns all records.

```
SELECT Count(c.IdCase) AS Number_of_Escalations, c.MonitoringTool, m.Location
FROM tblCases c
INNER JOIN tblAlerts a ON c.IdCase = a.refIdCase
INNER JOIN tblMembers m ON c.AddedBy = m.SOE
WHERE c.StartTime > '2014-10-01' AND a.Profile LIKE 'ITO%'
GROUP BY c.MonitoringTool, m.Location
```

When I remove first Inner join (and a.profile condition) it works as should.
StartTime is datetime type.

One case have multiple alerts assign. This is a problem. When I remove starttime condition I get more records. Is there anyway to pass this?

I'm trying to build Fiddle now. I'm not able to create it, sorry.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using; (2) What is the type of `StartTime`?  (3) Can you provide some sample data or create a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Do you have multiple alerts per case? If so, that might be why your experiencing a higher number than you expect.

Comment: Remove the first inner join and compare the values of c.IdCase with a.refIdCase

Comment: @EmmadKareem isn't that same difference, just potentially slower?

Comment: @Rhumborl, Spped is not the issue here, as far as I can see, the OP wants to debug the query.

Comment: @Tomasz will you be able to give the result set as well , When you remove the Alerts join?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing data samples and knowning your column properties, however, I can imagine that it might be a problem with the way you try to compare c.StartTime to your condition in plain text.

Try this:

```
[...]
c.StartTime > to_date('2014-10-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
[...]
```

Edit: Damn, missed your last sentence... Probably not the solution to your problem then ;-)